# It sounds like there is a "way" in "to **way** make sure that", what does that mean?

Tags: meaning

It sounds like the tutorial is [saying](https://youtu.be/rEnMEDo8Nzw?t=69) (a video link with a time stamp)

> because we want to make sure that these
>   don't flatten whatsoever while they're
>   baking, otherwise they'll basically just
>   be giant hamburger, but to **way**
>   make sure that they get nice and tall

It sounds like there is a "way" in "to **way** make sure that", what does that mean?

Comment: "basically they'll just be giant hamburger buns; we want to make sure...."

Comment: @user105719 Did you hear every single word exactly? I listened over and over again although I didn't hear "want to"; and "buns" sounds more like to be "but"

Comment: @user105719 Thanks for your comment. Did you hear a "t" between "bun" and "we"?

Comment: If by "exactly" you mean did I match the sounds to the words in the manner of an electronic device? No, certainly not. That's because I'm a native speaker, and my language processing is automatic enough that I don't have to listen to every sound before I understand what word is meant.  All the phonemes in question -- t, n, and s -- are alveolar, i.e, you place your tongue on roof of your mouth near your upper teeth (there’s something there that the anatomists call the alveolar ridge). The different sounds are produced by modulating the amount and location of air flow. (cont->)

Comment: (<-cont) Your tongue works overtime when you’ve got to produce two of these sounds in a row: bu**ns** or wan**t t**o, and articulation is harder. That’s why “want to” comes out as “wanna.”

Comment: If I listen carefully, I can hear a slight click after "buns," but I wouldn't have noticed it otherwise. That's because by the time I get to "we," there's no "t" sound that could make sense between "buns" and "we."